# Asp.net web-service being consumed by Java, and windows integrated authentication

Tags: java, asp.net, web-services, authentication

So I created a web-service for a co-worker to consume, but his department is using Java where everything my department is in .NET.  On top of that we have Windows Integrated Authentication turned on in our IIS server.  Is there some type of Java library/framework that provides windows integrated authentication credentials to Java clients?

I've found out more.  They're using Java 1.3, and they're on a different domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Java client should be able to consume your .NET service provided that you avoid [common interoperability issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/smguest/archive/2004/08/12/213659.aspx).  e.g. [reference vs. value types, arrays, weakly typed collections, etc](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4694/web-services-interoperability-between-j2ee-and-net-part-1/).

In terms of windows authentication, you don't mention the Java platform your co-worker is targeting.  Is it Java 1.4.2 or higher running on Windows?  If so, then you can use the [java.net.Authenticator class with the NTLM scheme](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html) to authenticate to the .NET service.

If not, then there doesn't seem to be that many choices.  The options seem to be [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/httpclient.html) which is free or [Oakland Software's commercial HTTP client](http://www.oaklandsoftware.com/product_http/overview.html).  I haven't used either of those so I can't recommend one over the other.

Another option would be change the IIS settings for your service to use a more Java friendly authentication scheme (Basic or Digest).

Comment: Well i think java.net.authenticator is out.  I might have to use Basic auth on the web service.